# octopress 3 installing plugin

Tags: rubygems, octopress

I am following this documentation for installing octopress 3 plugin. 
https://github.com/octopress/ink/blob/master/assets/docs/working-with-plugins.markdown
first I run command `gem install octopress-codefence` and
added this line to _config.yml

```
gems:
  - octopress-codefence
```

but when i run this command

```
octopress ink list octopress-codefence
```

following message was displayed.

Plugin 'octopress-codefence' not found.

Currently installed plugins:
You have no plugins installed.

Also followed this page 
https://github.com/octopress/codefence

Can anyone help how to install plugins in octopress 3. Also I don't know ruby and gem so bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

[Octopress Ink](https://github.com/octopress/ink) is a tool for making themes and plugins for Octopress. If I understand you correctly you just want to install the 'codefence' plugin to your blog. If so, you don't need Ink. If you want to list all the installed gems on your system, type the following in your terminal:

```
gem list
```

or

```
gem list octopress-codefence
```

if you just want see if a particular gem is installed, and what is its version number. [This post](http://www.sitepoint.com/octopress-3-arrives-to-make-blog-generation-crazy-simple/) covers the blog setup in detail.